# Interbase Domain Modification

Tags: interbase

Encountered an issue in IB (tested XE7 and IB 2017) when changing the size of a domain definition from something like VarChar(6) to VarChar(10). The end result is the field utilizing the domain ends up allowing 2 more characters (12 in this case) than the specified size.

Here are the steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new IB database
2. Create a domain definition of type VarChar(6)
3. Add new table "TestTable" with the following new fields:
   TestPK Integer, not null, Primary Key
   TestDomainField <-- use domain definition from step above
4. Test entry into the new table. It will allow 6 characters max (correct)
5. Alter the domain definition to VarChar(10)
6. Test entry in the table. It will allow *12* characters instead of the 10 specified on the domain (incorrect)

Metadata selection also confirms the allowed 12 characters:

SELECT distinct r.RDB$FIELD_NAME AS field_name,
f.RDB$FIELD_LENGTH AS field_length
FROM RDB$RELATION_FIELDS r
LEFT JOIN RDB$FIELDS f ON r.RDB$FIELD_SOURCE = f.RDB$FIELD_NAME
WHERE r.RDB$RELATION_NAME='TestTable'

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know exactly what is going on here, my hunch it is some sort of character set issue. IOW, some character sets allow multi-byte characters. So, you might experiment with adding a character set to your domain definition and see if that makes a difference.